# is there a way to clear a function after it executes?

Tags: jquery, mobile, swipe

Sorry if the title isn't clear. I have a swiperight and swipeleft event that when triggered adds an audio source into html5 audio tags with autoplay.  so if you swipe left one song plays and swipe right another plays..The problem is it only works once. if i swipe left the song plays then if i swipe right nothing, swipe left again nothing and vice versa. is there a way to reset the function? hope this makes sense and thanks! below is my code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").bind("swiperight", function(event){
        $('#swipe').append(
'<source src="http://a.tumblr.com/tumblr_ljdvcbDIsN1qhk4f9o1.mp3"/>');
    })

    $("body").bind("swipeleft", function(event) {
        $('#swipe').append('<source src="http://www.nerdthegame.com/media/audio/soundtrack/Nintendo-Super-Mario-Theme-Song.mp3" />');
    })
})
```

Comment: it's the id for the audio tag <audio id="swipe" autoPlay="autoplay"></audio>

Answer (score 1):

I believe the swipe event handlers execute every time, but then you `.append()` additional `<source>` elements into your `<audio>` element such that it ends up with multiple `<source>` elements. Try removing the previous `<source>` first, which you could do with `.empty()` as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").bind("swiperight", function(event){
        $('#swipe').empty().append(
'<source src="http://a.tumblr.com/tumblr_ljdvcbDIsN1qhk4f9o1.mp3"/>');
    })

    $("body").bind("swipeleft", function(event) {
        $('#swipe').empty().append('<source src="http://www.nerdthegame.com/media/audio/soundtrack/Nintendo-Super-Mario-Theme-Song.mp3" />');
    })
})
```

Seems to then work in a fiddle (I didn't use swipe events in the demo because I'm testing on a laptop not a phone): http://jsfiddle.net/AG3Tu/